# Pagination not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagination

This is code for which i got problem.
I have all data in return array but when i take them to pagination there was problem.

In pagination if i have 10 item per page and i press next then it shows second row of first page instead of to skip first 10 record

Link of plugin is as below

https://mac-blog.org.ua/wordpress-custom-database-table-example-full/

```
function prepare_items()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name     = $wpdb->prefix . 'cte'; // do not forget about tables prefix
    $per_page       = 10; // constant, how much records will be shown per page


    $paged = isset($_REQUEST['paged']) ? max(0, intval($_REQUEST['paged']) - 1) : 0;


    $current_page   = $this->get_pagenum();
    $columns        = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden         = array();
    $sortable       = $this->get_sortable_columns();

    // here we configure table headers, defined in our methods
    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);

    // [OPTIONAL] process bulk action if any
    $this->process_bulk_action();

    // will be used in pagination settings
    $total_items = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table_name");

    // prepare query params, as usual current page, order by and order direction                            
    $orderby = (isset($_REQUEST['orderby']) && in_array($_REQUEST['orderby'], array_keys($this->get_sortable_columns()))) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'name';

    $order = (isset($_REQUEST['order']) && in_array($_REQUEST['order'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc';


    // [REQUIRED] define $items array
    // notice that last argument is ARRAY_A, so we will retrieve array
    $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", $per_page, $paged), ARRAY_A);

    // [REQUIRED] configure pagination
    $this->set_pagination_args(array(
        'total_items' => $total_items, // total items defined above
        'per_page' => $per_page, // per page constant defined at top of method
        'total_pages' => ceil($total_items / $per_page) // calculate pages count
    ));
}
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome and what are you getting instead. "problem" isn't very specific...

Comment: @BrianH.in pagination if i have 10 item per page and i press next then it shows second row of first page instead of to skip first 10 record.I have edit question ,too

Answer (score 1):

If your second page is showing the second row from the first page, then you have a problem with the following line:

```
$this->items =
    $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", 
            $per_page, 
            $paged), 
        ARRAY_A);
```

In particular, I suspect that when you go to the second page, then `$paged == 1` which means your query results are offset by 1, and the data will start at row 2.

What you want, is that the offset that you pass to the query is:

```
offset = ($current_page - 1) * $per_page;
```

If `$paged`, in your code, is **meant** to be `$current_page - 1`, then change the above code to the following:

```
$this->items =
    $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", 
            $per_page, 
            $paged * $per_page), 
        ARRAY_A);
```